# Can cookies sent by PHP be disabled from the server?

Tags: php, apache, http, .htaccess, cookies

Can cookies sent by PHP be disabled from server?

Comment: Prevent PHP from starting to send cookies when starting a session: ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0); ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 0);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they can. You can do this using `.htaccess` by setting the following values:

```
Header unset Cookie
Header unset Set-Cookie
```

Please note that if the server has sent cookies to a browser in the past, then the browser might still be sending back cookies to the server.

Comment: And if you want to enable them from .htaccess?

Comment: @jorjap: They are usually enabled by default.

Comment: +1, then -1 again for not mentioning that cookies do not "belong" to PHP and that this is more of a HTTP issue.